# UFS2 filesystem - freebsd

Tags: filesystems, acl, freebsd

I'm trying to add 3 system calls in FreeBSD to set acl for a file in UFS2.

```
   int setacl(char *name, int type, int idnum, int perms);
   int clearacl(char *name, int type, int idnum);
   int getacl(char *name, int type, int idnum);
```

Would someone please tell me how to get started?

Comment: Just wondering why you want to do that? ACLs are supported by UFS2 and I assume the relevant system calls exist.

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search for 'freebsd ufs2 acls' yields this page:

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/fs-acl.html

You will probably want to read that page to discover that ufs2 acls already exist, and to learn a bit more about the implementation.

If you're looking for a generic start on FreeBSD kernel hacking, you may want to see if anyone has kept the 'junior kernel hacker' list up to date.  Poul-Henning Kamp used to update it ever summer, just in time for the Google Summer of Code announcements.